# Unable to Access API Key with PHP...any idea what's up?

Tags: php, json, urlencode

I am a junior programmer. Recently I've been trying to develop in PHP. I am trying to create a basic page about countries. For some reason I cannot grab the information from this API page. Can anyone give me some tips?

Here is what a sample country array looks like. Ideally I would like to try to grab the "name" attribute.

[image]

Here is my HTML and PHP:

```
<?php

if(!empty($_GET['country'])) {
$country_url = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/' . urlencode($_GET['country']) . '?fullText=true';
$country_json = file_get_contents($country_url);
$country_array = json_decode($country_url, true);
           }

?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset = "utf-8" />
            <title> PHP Country Practice </title>
        </head>
     <body>
        <form action="">
            <input type = "text" name = "country" />
            <button type="submit">submit </button>
        </form>

<?php

if(!empty($country_array)) {
    echo '<p> $country_array['name'] </p>';
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For starters: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Answer (score 0):

You're returning an associative array, so use identifiers like this:

```
$country_array[0]['name']
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. I get this error: syntax error, unexpected 'name' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Answer (score 0):

If it is object use the below code.

```
    echo $country_array[0]->name;
```

For array use

```
    echo $country_array[0]['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to access the correct array `index`, in this case `0`.
2. Variables **don't expand** inside **single-quotes**, you need to use
   **double-quotes** and surround it with brackets `{}` (tks [AbraCadaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2844319/abracadaver)), i.e.:

---

```
echo "<p> {$country_array[0]['name']} </p>";
```

Comment: Almost: `{$country_array[0]['name']}`